# Cannot find bounds of current function while debugging

Tags: c++

Hello guys can anyone tell me how do i fix this problem?When i debug in codeblocks and press the next line button it says "Cannot find bounds of current function".How do i fix this?here in the while loop i wanted to test out the debugger.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long int ll;
#define pb push_back
#define vint vector<int>
#define all(v) v.begin(), v.end()

int main()
{
    int n, i, in, x, sum1 = 0, sum2, t = 0;
    cin >> n;
    vint a;
    a.pb(0);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> in;
        a.pb(in);
        sum1 = sum1 + a[i];
    }

    in = 1;
    n = n + 1;
    while (in != 5) { // i want to debug from here.
        sum2 = sum1 + in;
        for (i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
            if (i == n + 1) {
                i = -1;
                continue;
            }
            sum2--;
            if (sum2 == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (i != 0) {
            t++;
        }
        in++;
    }

    cout << t << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to debug a release build perhaps?

Comment: you are aware that `#define vint vector<int>` and using it once is actually more to type than not using the macro?

Answer (score 1):

That usually means that there is no debug info found. Do you try to debug a release project maybe? For code/symbols to be present during debugging, you need to use a debug build.

Comment: how do i use debug build?

Comment: @AfeefAl'Hasnain you can open it in gdb for example and see the source code instead of disassembly. In gcc you can create a debug build by adding the `-g` Flag. Have a look at the gcc docs for details.